# Is there a word for the opposite of a gift

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

In the way that we can think of a gift as given under obligation, like to signify a relationship at Christmas or to show love for a spouse, is there a word for a thing taken. A word for that thing that we want to take back when someone takes something from us?

Comment: Can you give a sample sentence where you might use this word?

Comment: That’s the exact problem I’m having! I don’t think we have the conceptual framework to talk about it, but it’s an important part of the way we think about objects. Like we forget how inalienable they are until they are taken from us!

Comment: Perhaps _withholding (n.)_. (_OED_ definition of _withhold (v.)_: "To keep back; to keep in one's possession (what belongs to, is due to, or is desired by another); to refrain from giving, granting, or allowing.")

Comment: You mean taxes?  

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a price or charge, but that's only in business transactions. If someone takes something without permission, we usually just want that thing back, not something in exchange.

Comment: I'm also not sure you understand what a gift is. A gift is usually voluntary, not under obligation, although we have some traditional times when they're expected.

Comment: If they can't return the thing they took, what you want is reimbursement. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: So, someone takes something from you, that person owes you something.  The thing the person owes you (in exchange for the thing taken) is a *debt*.

Comment: The word *gift* exists because there is an established practice of gift-giving. It is not, however, obvious what **established social practice** could be regarded as the opposite of it. If there is no such practice, one should not expect there to be a word for it. If the OP thinks that the practice does exist, then the question should be elaborated to make it clear what it is, and to show that it is actually established, rather than merely hypothetical.

Comment: Repayment / reparation / restitution may be in the right ballpark, but I don't think they're ever as concrete as say a box of chocolates.

Answer (score 3):

If I give you a *gift*, I *reward* you with something.

In contrast, if I *take something away* from you, then I am either *punishing* or *penalizing* you. As such, I would say that, *in general*, the opposite of a *gift* is a **punishment** or **penalty**.

In terms of something *specific*, it would be a [**forfeiture**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forfeiture):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : the act of forfeiting : the loss of property or money because of a breach of a legal obligation
> // assets subject to *forfeiture*
> **2** : something (such as money or property) that is forfeited : PENALTY
>
> //  the *forfeiture* for early withdrawal of the investment savings will be an amount equal to 10 percent of the investment

Answer (score -1):

There is ***retribution***

Defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retribution) as:

> 3 : something given or exacted in recompense
> *especially* : PUNISHMENT

That thing we take back when someone takes something from us is retribution for what they've done.

Comment: Well, I don't often comment on unexplained downvotes, but this one seems ridiculous.  OP asks for a word "for that thing we want to take back when someone takes something from us."  That seems like retribution to me.  Especially when a retribution is a form of punishment which is an upvoted answer.  I wonder if anyone would care to explain why is so wrong that it deserves not just no vote, but a downvote.